# Open source tool to merge videos (VCD CD, DVD chapters) without losing too much data prior to encoding

Tags: software-rec, encoding, merge, video-editing, handbrake

Is there an opensource tool to merge videos alongside with encoding. Merge in a sense to merge vcd cd1 and vcd cd2. or to merge different chapters of dvd. can handbrake do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualDub would be my recommendation.  Just follow the directions here.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/merge-multiple-video-files-with-virtualdub/

**edit:**

Dat files and vob files are both MPEG formats in different container files.  If you want to output to mpeg, try AVIdemux.  It's more updated.

http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php

Comment: cool works for AVI. How about merging .dat files on VCD and .vob files on DVD.

Comment: I edited my answer.